# SSRS textbox clipping when exporting to PDF

Tags: sql, pdf, reporting-services, business-intelligence, ssrs-2012

I was working with an SSRS report that uses multiple textboxes in a list control. I found that when I ran and exported my report to PDF (and printed/exported to .XPS), *certain* textboxes would just ever so slightly get clipped.

**Note:** when the report rendered in SSRS development env., every textbox looked fine and the text never got clipped. The issue just occurs when exporting, and on seemingly random textboxes (random to me).

I've tried adjusting the height and width properties of the textboxes, and the CanGrow property to true/false. Even making the text a different size (like 5 point) or even a different font made no difference. The amount of text that filled the field didn't matter. I made sure the margins on the page were sufficient. I also made sure there were no other report objects that were overlapping the offending textboxes. Neighboring textboxes that displayed fine were set to be perfectly aligned vertically with ones that had the text problems, and still no luck.

None of these options above worked. I have also seen a few questions on stackoverflow that are similar, but not exact.

How do I keep these textboxes from clipping the text when exporting to PDF?

Thank you.

[Sample: textbox text is cut off very slightly on SSRS report exported to PDF for certain textboxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIEDr.png)

Comment: I have also seen this occasionally. In our case, it happens when a numeric field is all 1s before the decimal point, '$11,111.45' cuts off the 5 ever so slightly.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my own issue after some tinkering, though perhaps its not the best solution out there but it works.

I hard coded a space character at the end of each textbox field's expression that had the clipping issue,

For example:

=First(Fields!zipCode.Value) **+ " "**

The only minor draw back is that it shifts the alignment of the text left by one space. Hope this helps.

Comment: This should work great on single line values, not so good on paragraphs.  I think there is a property space after which might fulfil the same purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I played around with all sorts of options with indent, padding and even added a gutter column.  This seemed to work for a while but when the problem raised its head again, I just changed my font.

I think there might be something up with "Calibri" and "Calibri Light" but "Candara" seems fine.

Bit frustrating this only shows up on server generated pdfs as it makes the feedback loop so much longer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same clipping.

Not really a solution, but maybe it will help someone figure it out

I am pretty sure it has something to do with Kerning.

The Font I am using is Manrope. Arial and Calibri seem to work though.

[image]

This is how it looks in the preview:
[image]